# MCR 8.1 for MATLAB standalone executable

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to install MCR on a virtual machine, Windows server 2012 (that doesn't have MATLAB).
I manage to send the file over and run the installation program.
It installs with no problem.
But then I still get:

> Could not find version 8.1 of the MCR

Anyone has an idea?
I tried to do it as administrator as well, but doesn't matter.
Can I change some path or something manually?
The error message is also:

> attempting to load mclmcrrt8_1.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the machine you used to build the standalone, get the correct MCR version with the following command:

```
>> mcr
The WIN64 MCR Installer, version 8.2, is:
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\compiler\deploy\win64\MCRInstaller.exe

MCR installers for other platforms are located in:
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\compiler\deploy\<ARCH>
 <ARCH> is the value of COMPUTER('arch') on the target machine.

Full list of available MCR installers:
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\compiler\deploy\win64\MCRInstaller.exe

For more information, read your local MCR Installer help.
Or see the online documentation at MathWorks' web site. (Page may load slowly.)
```

Take the file it names and install it on the server. You *must match the architecture too*.

[Here are links to the installers](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried as you said. But it did not change anything. The VM cannot find it. Should I fix some paths or something? any more ideas?

Comment: @Johan Sorry to hear it.  You could manually copy the dlls needed (check [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)) or add the folder containing them to PATH and restart for good measure.